# The type or namespace name 'DynamicMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After converting my unity project to **iOS** this error appears, it works fine when the project is converted in **android**. `DynamicMethod` is using `System.Reflection.Emit.mata` file.
I'm using **unity 2020.3.3f1**

Comment: Error is coming from ultimateJson library .

Comment: Please do check for `using` directive hopefully it is not wrapped around something like `#if UNITY_ANDROID`, might be that can be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html):

**iOS** do not allow runtime code generation. Therefore, any managed code which depends upon **just-in-time (JIT)** compilation on the target device will fail. Instead, you must compile all of the managed code **ahead-of-time (AOT)**. Often, this distinction doesn’t matter, but in a few specific cases, **AOT** platforms require additional consideration.

An **AOT** platform cannot implement any of the methods in the `System.Reflection.Emit namespace`. The rest of `System.Reflection` is acceptable, as long as the compiler can infer that the code used via reflection needs to exist at runtime.